# UPSERT в MySQL не по первичному ключу

Tags: mysql, sql

Мне надо актуализировать базу данных. У меня есть какой-то набор значений, к примеру:

```
(id (первичный ключ), name, sku, ....)
```

Проблема в том, что id там не совпадают, а совпадает только поле `sku`. Ориентируясь на него надо либо вставить отсутствующие строки, либо обновить (**не заменить**) существующие.

Как я понял `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` ориентируется только на первичный ключ. А `REPLACE INTO` заменяет содержимое - тоже не подходит.

Есть какое-то элегантное решение или лучше написать костыль на стороне PHP?

Comment: *Как я понял INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ориентируется только на первичный ключ.* Неверно. На ВСЕ имеющиеся в структуре уникальные индексы, включая и первичный. Надеюсь, уникальный индекс по `sku` - имеется?

Comment: @Akina уже имеется) Думаю проблема решена

Comment: Наверное... более того, в INSERT .. ODKU вообще нет способа определить, какой из уникальных индексов вызвал срабатывание ODKU.